# how to sum temporary variables's value in xcode

Tags: xcode, variables, sum, temporary

I want TempScore to return to 0 just after being saved and added with the old value into the Score variable

```
if (self.currentQuestion < [self.questions count]) {


_TempScore = x;
_Score = y;
_Score = x + y;
x = 0;
}
```

why doesn't that work?

EDIT: Made it work

```
self.x = self.TempScore;

self.y = self.Score;

self.Score = self.x + self.y ;

self.TempScore = 0;
```

Comment: self.Score is the same as _Score with the exception the setter is not called. self.TempScore and _TempScore are similarly related. Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks I pasted some old lines I forgot to cut

Comment: @lea51294 what are you trying to do? You're just setting `_TempScore` and `_Score` to `0`?

Comment: I want tempscore to return to 0 just after being saved and added with the old value into the score variable

Comment: Do you understand what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Made it work by doing this

```
self.x = self.TempScore;
self.y = self.Score;
self.Score = self.x + self.y ;
self.TempScore = 0;
```